# Getting content vales in a Orchard workflow

Tags: orchardcms

What I'm trying to do is send an email when a particular content type is created in Orchard.

What I did was create a workflow that detects when a "Practice" type is created and send an email.

Initially I hard coded everything (email address, subject and body).  I am getting an email every time a "Practice" type is created.

I then tried using tokens to get real values.  Initially I tried..

`{Content.ContentType}` and
`{Content.Id}`

Those seem to be working.  The ContentType is "Practice" and the Id is the correct value.

The Practice type has a field called "ContactEmail", but I can't seem to get that value to show up.  Here are the different variations I've tried...

```
{Content.Fields.Practice.ContactEmail}
{Content.ContactEmail}
{Content.Practice.ContactEmail}
```

but it's always blank (testing by putting these fields in the email body).

Any suggestions on how to the the "ContactEmail" value from a Practice?

Thanks!

Additional info...

The Practice part is created from a module (i.e. migration, model, etc.).  What I think I may have to do is create a token provider for the Practice part.  Does that sound right?

Comment: try `{Content.ContentItem.Practice.ContactEmail.Value}`

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't work

Comment: If you're using version 1.10 you might have to add a `#` in front of the token to make it work. I haven't really figured out when this is or isn't necessary because it seems inconsistent but it's an issue that popped up for me recently.
`#{Content.Fields.Practice.ContactEmail}`

Comment: That also didn't work

Comment: Are you using the `Content Created` event to trigger the Workflow? It might only work with `Content Published`.

Comment: You need to create the token provider for your custom type.